# How to start the operations when application enter into foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

i am doing one application.In that i am animating the images.When i click the pause button,i am stopping the animations.So imageviews are ideal.So when i enter into background and come to foreground in that time,imageviews are not appearing.So please tell me how to get that imageviews.

Comment: You just want to get images start animating again when app comes to foreground. Am i right?

Comment: Show us what u have tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

like that you can do  .

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
       applicationFromBackground = TRUE;
    }


- (void)stop
{

  // Create AppDelegate instance
  AppDelegate *objectAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  if(objectAppDelegate.applicationFromBackground)
  {
     applicationFromBackground = FALSE;
     **//do what u want**.
  }

}
```

[referthis](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: Where i can call this stop method.